# how to query the sql to get the count

Tags: mysql

Assume I have the following table

```
version  is_success(only 1 and 0)
0.1      0
0.1      0
0.1      1
0.1      1
0.2      0
0.2      0
0.2      0
```

I want to query the following result by sql:

```
version   count(is_success=0)/count(all based on is_success type)
0.1       2/4=0.5
0.2       3/3=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT version, 1.0 * SUM(is_success = 0) / COUNT(*) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY version;
```

Comment: Just for curiosity why using `1.0 *` when `SUM(is_success = 0) / COUNT(*)` gives the correct result

Comment: @ErgestBasha Some databases automatically convert the quotient to float, others don't.  I can never remember which.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want the average value of `NOT is_success`:

```
SELECT version,
       AVG(NOT is_success) avg_not_success
FROM tablename
GROUP BY version;
```

or:

```
SELECT version,
       AVG(is_success = 0) avg_not_success
FROM tablename
GROUP BY version;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=336b27566c11309685e23cab4b7ff229).

Answer (score 1):

i hope this works fine

```
select version, count(if(is_success=0, version,null))/count(version) As result from yourTable where is_success>=0 group by version;
```